# Определение локали пользователя приложением

Tags: c, локализация

Как корректно сформулировать мою задачу, мне не известно вполне, но суть проста. Я пишу маленькое приложение и нужно, чтобы помимо основного английского языка, оно поддерживало, ну хотя бы русский. Многие приложения определяют настройку локали системы и выводят в терминал кириллицу (например, компиллятор gcc). Вот, к примеру, кусок кода:

```
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 1;
}
```

Если локаль системы RU, то должно, по хорошему, выводиться:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Невозможно открыть базу данных: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

Вопрос, собственно такой: как научить приложение определять локаль и выводить текст на языке пользователя. Т. е. нужно что-то вроде:

```
fprintf(stderr, LANG["connect_m"]"%s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

А уже в корне лежат два файлика с переводами (типа «ru_RUS.c», «en_EN.c») и они по ситуации подключаются. В них что-то в роде:

```
// Lang RU

LANG["hello"] = "Привет, по писят граммов?";
LANG["taxon_i"] = "Введите латинское (биноминальное) название таксона";
LANG["connect_m"] = "Невозможно открыть базу данных: ";
...
```

Я в этом деле совсем новичок, не судите строго, но окажите помощь :)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, понятно. Это какая-то сторонняя библиотека? Возможно ли «штатными» средствами, чтобы у приложения было меньше зависимостей? Просто, не очень удобно с маленьким приложением тянуть дополнительные библиотеки :)

Comment: Это сторонняя библиотека, затронута будет только сборка. Сама библиотека очень лёгкая. Или используйте её как источник вдохновения: [Locale-Environment-Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Locale-Environment-Variables).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо большое! Собственно решение вопроса :)